# Can I connect an output pin to an input pin to measure it's voltage on a single board?

Tags: pins, pwm

So just bought an arduino Uno and I've been playing around with it. I want to connect one of the input pins to one of the PWM outputs and measure the output from there by sending it to my computer through `Serial` and then plot it in python.

Sorry if this is a basic question.
Thanks

Comment: PWM pins don't give an analog value. They are either 0v of 5v. Your idea is possible, but you'll receive almost exclusively 0's and 1023's.

Comment: ok cool, I'm just worried that I'll burn out the board...

Comment: That won't happen here. Just be careful to never connect two pins that are both outputs (as setting one to HIGH and the other to LOW would create a short). If you want to be super-save, you could put a resistor between the two pins (e.g. 1kΩ) instead of a wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PWM are digital output pins, and it seems that you wish to measure analog equivalent voltage generated by PWM output. If so, you'd need a filter.

Construct a unity gain op-amp based RC filter with cut-off frequency significantly smaller than PWM clock frequency. This will generate a analog waveform that can drive analog circuits. You could connect this to ADC input pin.

You could Google "Active low pass filter" for a lot of schematics and formula.

BUT

To be able to faithfully reproduce analog signal captured through ADC on a computer screen graph, your ADC sample rate must be more than ~2.5 times analog signal's bandwidth.

If your sample rate is close to Nyquist rates,  you'd need to filter (interpolate) your digitized signal in software to generate a smooth graph. This is a bit involved in maths and software. Otherwise you'd only get a "spikey" waveform.

Or preferably have a sample rate > 10 times analog bandwidth. This will give large enough sample counts to reliably show analog data without much processing.

Comment: nope not interested in an "analog equivalent voltage". I just wanted to measure the PWM waveform, and wasn't sure if by using the same board for measuring and generating (of the signal) I could potentially burn it out

Comment: Usually digital waveforms are better captured by counters + interrupts, because exact voltage level is usually of no concern. i.e. for all transitions (hi->lo, lo->high), trigger interrupt. In ISR record a timer counter value and store. Capture timer clock needs to be (much) faster than PWM clock